# Accurate and free geocoding service for ip geolocation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding

What is a good and free geocoding service that reliably determines the city of a given ip? I'd like there to be a Ruby gem I can plug it into.

I'm currently using the Geocoder gem. Is there any way I can plug in alternatives to FreeGeoIP (what are those alternatives)? When I plug in a Manhattan ip, it returns Mount Vernon for the city, rather than New York.

This is what I'm using it for:

[tmrw.am](http://www.tmrw.am)

## Edit

Geokit seems to do a pretty good job for certain ips that FreeGeoIP struggles with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geokit seems to do a pretty good job for certain ips that FreeGeoIP struggles with.